# django registration page with country , state field after submission

Tags: python, django, forms

I have  created a django form using django-registration package.

In that I have two selection fields , first is country, second is state depending on the country.  If I get any errors,  when I submit the form it returns form with user filled data.

But I am facing problems with selection field of country and state.

Please give me idea to solve this

Comment: You mean it should return the selection but not user filled data?

Comment: it should return what user selected in form when summiting form

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your case in admin of Django. There is a request object in Django which I suppose you know what it is. You can get user selection by `request.user.user_permissions.select_related()`.  Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of filtered forms can be easily done using Dajax. If I understand correctly, you want to do something along the lines of http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/

I have tried this before and it helps make great filtered forms. If not Dajax, your other option is to write JavaScript to send your form data to your view and then fetch your state depending on your country and append the new choices to your state selection field.